# s3: checksum attribute is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get checksum of a s3 object.

First, I've upload it using:

```bash
$ aws s3api put-object --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key $KEY --body pom.xml
{
  "ETag": "\"44a7a97ddff52b27557a39cb2983ae62\"",
  "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256"
}
```

When I'm trying to get checksum:

```bash
$ aws s3api get-object-attributes --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key $KEY --object-attributes "ObjectSize" "Checksum"
{
  "LastModified": "2024-03-08T06:34:49+00:00",
  "ObjectSize": 2097
}
```

I've also tried putting the object setting `--checksum-algorithm`:

```bash
$ aws s3api put-object --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key $KEY --body pom.xml --checksum-algorithm SHA256
{
  "ETag": "\"44a7a97ddff52b27557a39cb2983ae62\"",
  "ChecksumSHA256": "ZR6CNpjrGvQWPPkaHiAeTWm2La1ZZIHLjtrFaPjnaPc=",
  "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256"
}
```

Then, I'm able to get calculated checksum:

```bash
$ aws s3api get-object-attributes --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key $KEY --object-attributes "ObjectSize" "Checksum" | yq .
{
  "LastModified": "2024-03-08T06:39:19+00:00",
  "Checksum": {
    "ChecksumSHA256": "ZR6CNpjrGvQWPPkaHiAeTWm2La1ZZIHLjtrFaPjnaPc="
  },
  "ObjectSize": 2097
}
```

I'm aware of sometimes `ETag` is a MD5 checksum, but ohter times no.

Is above behavior the default one? I mean, is checksum attribute not calculated by default?

The problem is that I'm creating PUT presigned urls and send it some client. Client is responsible to make the push to the PUT presigned url received.

After that, I receive an S3 event, and then I need to get the checksum attribute of just created s3 object.

Comment: What's wrong with the using the command (third one) that works?